# pass multiple arguments to an EXE from Windows form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, process, inputstream, windows

I have an app.exe application that asks to enter **input path** string, once i enter, it asks **output path** string... now when i enter, app.exe perform some operation

i need to pass these paths from my Window Form Application
i saw a lot of questions like this but could not implement what i require because i never worked with processes and Stream Reader or Writer
any help please... examples will be thanked.. thank you..

```
        string input = @"C:\Documents and Settings\pankaj\Desktop\My File\greetingsfreinds.ppt";
        string output = @"C:\Documents and Settings\pankaj\Desktop\test";
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wondershare\MyApp\app.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit(3000);
        process.Close();
```

---

ok i tried that
but its giving some exception
**StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet**...
  my code was

```
        string input = @"C:\Documents and Settings\pankaj\Desktop\My File\greetingsfreinds.ppt";
        string output = @"C:\Documents and Settings\pankaj\Desktop\test";
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wondershare\MyApp\app.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = input + ";" + output;
        process.Start();
        string Strout = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
```

Comment: is any one there to solve and help
i am still struggling

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) for this.

```
    Process process = new Process()
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Wondershare\MyApp\app.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    ....
    process.Arguments = input + " " + output;
```

Comment: i tried that but its not working ( through an exception ).. i have to Supply my arguments one by one to app.exe

Comment: so you have to pass one argument per time ?

Comment: @PankajDubey: also set process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true.